# Excel Blank Cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to eliminate excel from leaving cells blank when pulling information from different tabs. I have three shifts for volunteers (1,2,3) which are assigned on the "full contact info" tab. I would like the Shift Schedule tab to populate only those that meet the criteria and not have blank cells. This is the formula I am working with now:

```
=IF('Full contact info'!H2=1,'Full contact info'!A2,"")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, right now you're just doing a 1:1 move of information across tabs. What you want to do is loop through each cell in the volunteer tab, and when you find a viable volunteer, you append to the shift schedule. Append will fill the last empty space therefore you never have an empty space.

Comment: Also could you include your code? It's very difficult to understand what is going on...

Comment: I believe that he is looking for a formula only solution.

Comment: If possible I would like to do it with a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula that worked:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Full contact info'!$A$2:$A$30,SMALL(IF('Full contact info'!$H$2:$H$30=COLUMNS($A:A),ROW('Full contact info'!$H$2:$H$30)-COLUMNS($A:A)),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```